# Crontab running python scripts

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

So im trying to make my ec2 instance to automatically run a python script that through Google API generates a csv with Google Analytics data. 
When i run:

> python /path/script.py

it works fine but i set up this line in crontab

> @reboot python /path/script.py

And even when the file is generated non data shows up, i believe at some point the script is failing. Any idea what could be causing this? Or how can i debug the problem? is there a log of the instance start so i can see what happens after crontab run the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect std_err and std_out to a separate file.

```
@reboot python /path/script.py 2>&1 /tmp/<file.log>
```

Comment: Thank, at the end the problem was an encode error, solved replacing print function for one that .encode('UTF-8') the text first and the prints.